# C++, Why does my function with an auto type as parameter not work?

Tags: c++, auto

I have a class that for simplicity we call Cell, it has 3 variables:

- mark
- colorMark
- backgroundColor

a constructor and a function

*Cell.h:*

```
#pragma once
#include "macro.h"

using namespace std;

class Cell    
{
    public:
    Cell(char mark, int markColor, int backgroundColor);
    void set_value(int parameter, auto value);
    int x, y, markColor, backgroundColor;
    char mark;
};
```

*Cell.cpp:*

```
Cell::Cell(char mark, int markColor, int backgroundColor)
{
    Cell::x = -1;
    Cell::y = -1;
    Cell::mark = mark;
    Cell::markColor = markColor;
    Cell::backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

void Cell::set_value(int parameter, auto value)
{
    switch (parameter)
    {
        case PARAMETER_MARK:
            Cell::mark = value;
            break;
        
        case PARAMETER_MARK_COLOR:
            Cell::markColor = value;
            break;
        
        case PARAMETER_BK_COLOR:
            Cell::backgroundColor = value;
            break;
    }
}
```

And then I have a class called **Painter** that deals with manipulating the parameters of a cell vector through transformations.

​

*Painter.h:*

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "Cell.h"

using namespace std;

typedef vector <Cell> element_cells;

using namespace std;

class Painter
{
    public:
        Painter(element_cells* cells);
        Painter();

        void set_cells(element_cells* cells);
        void paint(int parameter, int paintType, auto value);

        element_cells* cells;
        size_t numberCells;
};
```

**The most important function of Painter is paint(...)**, it takes two integers one to specify the cell parameter to be modified and the other to specify the type of transformation to be applied to the cell vector, **the last parameter is a value needed for almost all types of transformation, as in these transformations the value type is not constant I need a auto type**.

**To specify the cell parameter and the type of transformation I use macros**

​

*Painter.cpp*

```
...
void Painter::paint(int parameter, int paintType, auto value)
{
    int i;
    switch (paintType)
    {
        case PAINT_TYPE_SINGLE:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value);
            }
            break;
        }

        case PAINT_TYPE_SCALAR:
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value.at(j));
                j = (j < (value.size() - 1)) ? j += 1 : j = 0;
            }

            break;
        }

        case PAINT_TYPE_RANDOM:
        {
            int casualNum;
            srand(time(NULL));
            for (int i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                if (parameter == PARAMETER_MARK)
                    do { casualNum = rand() % 256; } while ((casualNum < 32) || (casualNum == 127));
                else
                    casualNum = rand() % 16;

                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value);
            }
            break;
        }

        case PAINT_TYPE_RANDOM_BETWEEN:
        {
            int casualNum;
            srand(time(NULL));

            for (int i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                casualNum = rand() % value.size();
                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value.at(casualNum));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**But when I execute this code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Painter.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    element_cells cells;
    Cell defaultCell;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cells.push_back(defaultCell);
    }

    Painter p(&cells);
    p.paint(PARAMETER_MARK, PAINT_TYPE_SINGLE, 'A');

    for (i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Cell " << i << "*) " << "| x: " << cells.at(i).x << " | y: " << cells.at(i).y << " | mark: " << cells.at(i).mark << " | colorMark: " << cells.at(i).markColor << " | Background Color: " << cells.at(i).backgroundColor << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**The compiler returns the following error:**

```
`Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion Status Error LNK2019 reference to the external symbol "public: void __cdecl Painter::paint<char>(int,int, char)" (??$paint@D@Painter@@QEAAXHHD@Z) not resolved in the main function AreaTest C:\Users\albya\Personal\Programming\C++\Software Challenge - 2022\AreaTest\AreaTest\AreaTest.obj 1`

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion Status Error LNK1120 1 external unresolved AreaTest C:\Users\albya\Personal\Programming\C++\Software Challenge - 2022\AreaTest\x64\Debug\AreaTest.exe 1`
```

**the same thing happens when I use templates and any (for cell):**

​

*Cell.h:*

```
...
void set_value(int parameter, any value);
...
```

*Cell.cpp:*

```
...
void Cell::set_value(int parameter, any value)
{
    switch (parameter)
    {
        case PARAMETER_MARK:
            Cell::mark = any_cast<char>(value);
            break;

        case PARAMETER_MARK_COLOR:
            Cell::markColor = any_cast<int>(value);
            break;

        case PARAMETER_BK_COLOR:
            Cell::backgroundColor = any_cast<int>(value);
            break;
    }
}
...
```

​

*Painter.h:*

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>

#include "Cell.h"

using namespace std;

typedef vector <Cell> element_cells;

using namespace std;

class Painter
{
    public:
        Painter(element_cells* cells);
        Painter();

        void set_cells(element_cells* cells);

        template <typename tmpType>
        void paint(int parameter, int paintType, tmpType value);
        
        element_cells* cells;
        size_t numberCells;
};
```

​

*Painter.cpp:*

```
...

template <typename tmpType>
void Painter::paint(int parameter, int paintType, tmpType value)
{
    int i;
    
    switch (paintType)
    {
        case PAINT_TYPE_SINGLE:
        {
            for (i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value);
            }

            break;
        }

        case PAINT_TYPE_SCALAR:
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value.at(j));
                j = (j < (value.size() - 1)) ? j += 1 : j = 0;
            }

            break;
        }

        case PAINT_TYPE_RANDOM:
        {
            int casualNum;

            srand(time(NULL));
            for (int i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                if (parameter == PARAMETER_MARK)
                    do { casualNum = rand() % 256; } while ((casualNum < 32) || (casualNum == 127));
                else
                    casualNum = rand() % 16;

                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value);
            }

            break;
        }
        
        case PAINT_TYPE_RANDOM_BETWEEN:
        {
            int casualNum;

            srand(time(NULL));
            for (int i = 0; i < Painter::numberCells; i++)
            {
                casualNum = rand() % value.size();
                Painter::cells->at(i).set_value(parameter, value.at(casualNum));
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Main:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Painter.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    element_cells cells;
    Cell defaultCell;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cells.push_back(defaultCell);
    }

    Painter p(&cells);

    p.paint<char>(PARAMETER_MARK, PAINT_TYPE_SINGLE, 'A');

    for (i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Cell " << i << "*) " << "| x: " << cells.at(i).x << " | y: " << cells.at(i).y << " | mark: " << cells.at(i).mark << " | colorMark: " << cells.at(i).markColor << " | Background Color: " << cells.at(i).backgroundColor << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The compiler returns the following error:**

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion Status Error LNK2019 reference to the external symbol "public: void __cdecl Painter::paint<char>(int,int,char)" (??$paint@D@Painter@@QEAAXHHD@Z) not resolved in the main function AreaTest C:\Users\albya\Personal\Programming\C++\Software Challenge - 2022\AreaTest\AreaTest\AreaTest.obj 1


Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion Status Error LNK1120 1 external unresolved AreaTest C:\Users\albya\Personal\Programming\C++\Software Challenge - 2022\AreaTest\x64\Debug\AreaTest.exe 1
```

As I understand it, the error, in both ways, with auto and with templates, lies in the fact that it does not see the definition of functions with auto/template.

If the error is this, I don't know how to fix it, could someone tell me how,

**thanks in advance**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: In `Cell` don't name the constructor arguments like member variables, use a member initializer list. If you reorder it so `x` and `y` are at the end you can use aggregate initializaion and don't need a constructor at all. Using `auto` in `set_value` makes it a template function. But a really bad one. The type should depend on the `parameter`, which really should not be an `int`.  Why not replace `parameter` with a member pointer? Then you can match the type of the pointer with the type of the value? That also removes the need to `switch`. Actually you don't need the `set_value` function at all

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow, Do you think my code is wrong?, I did it because I previously had 4 functions repeating for each cell parameter (3), for a total of 12 functions.

I therefore wanted to group and compact the code.

What do you think?

Comment: As said I would just use a member pointer to pick the value and the whole question goes away.